# Applying composition over inheritance to Vehicle classes

Tags: c#, design, inheritance, composition

I have a car maintenance garage program that has an abstract `Vehicle` class that has several derived classes like `Car` `MotorCycle`, etc. Each of those derived vehicles in turn is either a fuel or an electric vehicle. So instead of having a `FuelCar`, `ElectricCar`, `FuelMotorCycle`, `ElectricMotorCycle` etc, I'm trying to implement it using composition.

The problem now is that I would have to check all the time if it's an electric or fuel vehicle, and then do `as cast` (that's like reinterpret_cast from c++) accordingly, or would have to wrap each `as cast` with `try catch`. It adds complexity to the code.

Another option was removing the `EnergySource` empty class and have each vehicle to hold both `Fuel` and `Electric` and to initialize only one in the ctor, but it doesn't seem right to have a fuel car that also have an electric part (even if that part is null). Although this seems the simplest of the three.

Any suggestions on what is the best approach?

Here's the UML diagram of what I currently have:

[image]

Code: http://pastebin.com/Rt5HccHC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @radarbob those members are specified, I didn't choose them.

My sympathies.

---

> ... Hybrid cars shouldn't be allowed and are irrelevant.

Ok. Then you'd better not have both a `Fuel` and `Electric` properties in `Vehicle`. It "sends the wrong message."

---

> ... I don't see how placing properties in interfaces help here, I'm still in square one.

Throughout the StackExchange universe I see the way over-use of `interface`s (the keyword kind). I think it is an exuberant mis-application and mis-understanding of "code to interfaces not implementation."

---

> ... Lastly, you mean a solid rhombus en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Relationships

[Jessica Simpson on UML](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zrCAYJ0aJ4)

---

> ... Anything else you would like to add?

Yes.

**Wrap a `Vehicle` in a `VehicleEnergy` class**

Given the design as shown, pass a `Vehicle` instance into a `VehicleEnergy` class with appropriate wrapper methods, or properties, to query the vehicle-EnergySource kind that it is.  But I don't see how you can get around the fact that somewhere, somehow you have to interrogate the object.

This feels like a good separation of concerns compromise. I wonder if the flurry of comments on this thread is the result of - a symptom of - conflicting concerns.

I think this hybrid design (pun intended) expresses the separate aspects and then expresses their interaction in a coherent interface (the non-keyword kind).

The `Vehicle` object can always be used as-is, or disguise itself, so to speak.

Oh, yes... I might use the factory pattern and pass in an `enum` for the vehicle-enery desired. There will be no enum member for a hybrid vehicle so this becomes a strongly typed way of communicating that "hybrid" is undefined.

Comment: For the record, usually when I say "code to an interface",  I'm not talking about the keyword.

Comment: By "wrap" do you mean to have nested classes or `vehicle` would be a data member of `VehicleEnergy` ?

Comment: @kuhaku I think he's talking about the decorator pattern. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: "wrap" == `Vehicle` contained in a `VehicleEnergy` class. I see that `Vehicle` already contains a `EnergySource` property. I see the `Vehicle` doing no more that it must to appropriately expose that property; likewise for `EnergySource` expressing itself. Then a separate class has the burden of that "interplay functionality." It isolates any messiness of dynamic functionality and potential sub-class proliferation; and essentially expresses vehicle-energysource dynamics as an independent construct. This certainly should avoid the "2 EnergySource property problem" mentioned in the OP.

Comment: re: "decorator pattern. Conceptually I was thinking more like a facade. The thought was to keep "vehicle + energy" identity separate from Vehicle. My spidey-sense is telling me there may be some bigger picture domain/design conflicts here in extending `Vehicle` functionality, but that is no more than a vague suspicion

Answer (score 4):

A car has an `Engine` and `Fuel` whether it be combustion or electric. They're your `abstract` base classes. Then, a car *has a* `Engine` and it shouldn't care if that engine is a `CombustionEngine` or an `ElectricEngine`.

Comment: This would be the same as the UML diagram only `EnergySource` = `Engine`, I don't see how it solves the problem.

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question for me.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to do `as cast` and would prefer to have the compiler know if a car is electric or not without having to hint it. Having an abstract base class with derivatives for gasoline and electricity forces me to do `as cast` quite a bit. Wouldn't it be preferable to ditch the base class for the two fuel types? Or those `as casts` are unavoidable?

Comment: Please explain why your code needs to know the type. If a car needs to know what type of engine it has, you're breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle and aren't coding to interfaces. I think that's likely your problem. Can we see some example code?

Comment: I don't have interfaces because they can't hold fields, maybe the `EnergySource` can be an interface instead but it's less of a concern now. I'm pasting the code into pastebin now.

Comment: Added the code, the `Motorcycle` and `Truck` classes are similar to `Car` so no point to clutter it with them.

Comment: This isn't true- you can't mix electricity with a petrol engine or petrol fuel with an electric engine.

Comment: I just looked at your code @kuhaku. Go learn about properties. Those *can* be in interfaces (and abstract classes). Your abstract base class needs to define a common set of methods and properties. Forget about the implementation details of combustion and electric for now and focus on the methods `Car` will need to call on `EnergySouce` (`Start`, `Accelerate`, `Stop`, etc.), then figure out how to provide those methods. Design top down. Maybe go do some research. Car : Vechichle is a common example used in books/tutorials on OOP.

Comment: @DeadMG that's a problem for `FillFuel` method. That one will need to do some type checking, but let's not confuse the beginner here.

Comment: Then what you really need is to make `Car` an `abstract` class and to make an `ElectricCar` and a `CombustionEngineCar`. Then each of those knows how to deal with their own kind of fuel.

Comment: It's a maintenance garage, there's no need for `start`, `accelerate` etc, the methods you see are all the specified methods for those classes. (Maybe other than wrapper methods needed in `car` for the refuel and recharge).

Comment: @RubberDuck but that will mean having to duplicate the `electricX` and `CombustionEngineX` for the motorcycle and truck and every other vehicle...

Comment: Then code to interfaces.

Comment: @RubberDuck By that you mean for example to have an `ElectricCar` that will be derived from `Car` and also implements `IElectric`?

Comment: `enum` anyone? Also, all the `Fuel` and `Electric` class members are nonsensical.  These are more like attributes of a fuel tank, or of a vehicle.

Comment: *"you can't mix electricity with a petrol engine or petrol fuel with an electric engine."*  What is a hybrid vehicle if not that?

Comment: The OP's concept is broken. You just cannot proliferate hybrid classes based on what should be properties just so the compiler "answers the questions about what it is" at compile time, vice actual code at run time. As RubberDuck says you really must get a better understanding of properties. Go back to the drawing board. Our answers will not get any better until then.  P.S. a solid arrow means composition, not inheritance.

Comment: @radarbob those members are specified, I didn't choose them. Hybrid cars shouldn't be allowed and are irrelevant. I don't see how placing properties in interfaces help here, I'm still in square one. Lastly, you mean a solid rhombus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Relationships Anything else you would like to add?